# Create Mongodb Database Script from existing database

Tags: mongodb

How to Generate a script from existing MongoDB that will prepare the Schema and create empty database.

Purpose is to be able to edit schema when a developer changes it so rest of the developer can use this script to alter their database with the changed schema. As a Result we can later implement this in Jenkins Pipeline to alter any changes also in database.

Comment: Since MongoDB is a flexible-schema database, you don't need to alter anything. You can just insert a new document with the new "schema" and it will be fine database-wise. Not sure about application-wise. If this is not what you need, could you elaborate more on your use case and also give some example of what you have in mind?

Comment: @Kevin Adistambha i have a mongodb database named student and it has 7 collection. I want to generate script from student database that will generate all collection empty script. Later on i will run my script command in to another mondodb server to create new database.

Comment: MongoDB will automatically create new database and collections for you if it doesn't yet exists. You don't need to do create table etc. like in SQL databases. Have you seen https://university.mongodb.com ? There are free courses that will get you up to speed to use MongoDB effectively.